# Export Function With Same Name As Win32 API Function

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I have a project that I export a function named BlockInput from. This function is my own, however there is also a Win32 API named BlockInput found within User32. Because of this, exporting my function as BlockInput causes the compiler to assume User32.BlockInput is being referred to and exports that instead.

My exports are done as follows:

**MyHeader.h**

```cpp
ELITEAPI_API void __stdcall BlockInput(void* apiObject, bool block);
```

**exports.def**

```cpp
BlockInput
```

There are about ~100 total exports from this DLL which all work fine, just this one has an issue due to a system API sharing the same name. Is there a way to export this function without having to rename it to something else? Can I force the .def file to use my function specifically instead of the one found in user32 first?

Comment: You can rename the function in your .def file, so it exports MyBlockInput as BlockInput. However, you still have the problem of clients dealing with two definitions for BlockInput, one from your DLL and one from user32.

Comment: That route is something I'm trying to avoid. I'd rather be able to block user32's BlockInput from being seen at all if possible.

Comment: You can just change it in the header file. `#ifdef MYDLL_IMPLEMENTATION` `#define BlockInput MyBlockInput`. You probably already have this `#ifdef` so you can change the definition of `ELITEAPI_API`.